# Avoid repeating named argument defaults when calling superclass initializer in Ruby (2.1+)

Tags: ruby, superclass, named-parameters

Say I have parent class whose initializer has an argument with a default value:

```
class Parent
  attr_reader :foo
  def initialize(foo: 123)
    @foo = foo
  end
end
```

I want to create a subclass that has the same default value for `foo`. I can do this if I repeat the declaration:

```
class Child < Parent
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize(foo: 123, bar: 456)
    super(foo: foo)
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

However, this means I have to write `123` twice. If I try to avoid repeating it by leaving it out --

```
class Child < Parent
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize(foo:, bar: 456)
    super(foo: foo)
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

-- this now means that the formerly optional, defaulted `foo` is now *required* by the subclass, and I don't actually get any benefit from the default value at all.

I thought I might be able to default it to `nil` in the subclass --

```
class Child < Parent
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize(foo: nil, bar: 456)
    super(foo: foo)
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

-- but no; `Child.new(bar:789).foo` is now `nil`, when what I wanted was `123`.

I can't leave the leave the argument out entirely, either --

```
class Child < Parent
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize(bar: 456)
    super(foo: foo)
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

-- because then if I do try to specify it (`Child.new(foo: 345, bar:789)`) I get `unknown keyword: foo (ArgumentError)`.

Is there any way to actually *leave an argument out*, as opposed to giving it a default value? And/or a way to allow an initializer to take arbitrary additional named paraemetrs and pass them to its superclass initializer?

---

**Update:** I came up with the following hack (hand-rolling my own 'default parameters', basically) but I'm not very happy about it.

```
class Parent
  attr_reader :foo
  def initialize(foo: nil)
    @foo = foo || 123 # faking 'default'-ness
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize(foo: nil, bar: 456)
    super(foo: foo)
    @bar = bar
  end
end
```

Surely there's some more Ruby-ish way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Ruby 2.0+, you can use the double splat operator.

```
def initialize(bar: 456, **args)
  super(**args)
  @bar = bar
end
```

An example:

```
[1] pry(main)> class Parent
[1] pry(main)*   def initialize(a: 456)
[1] pry(main)*     @a = a
[1] pry(main)*   end  
[1] pry(main)* end  
=> :initialize
[2] pry(main)> class Child < Parent
[2] pry(main)*   def initialize(b: 789, **args)
[2] pry(main)*     super(**args)
[2] pry(main)*     @b = b
[2] pry(main)*   end  
[2] pry(main)* end  
=> :initialize
[3] pry(main)> ch = Child.new(b: 3)
=> #<Child:0x007fc00513b128 @a=456, @b=3>
[4] pry(main)> ch = Child.new(b: 3, a: 6829)
=> #<Child:0x007fc00524a550 @a=6829, @b=3>
```

The double splat operator is similar to the single splat operator, but instead of capturing all of the extra args into an array, it captures them into a hash.  Then when used as an argument to super, the double splat flattens the hash into named parameters, kind of like the single splat does for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Ruby-1.9-ish way than a Ruby-2.1-ish way, but I believe it does what you want while avoiding repetition:

```
class Parent
  attr_reader :foo
  def initialize(opts = {})
    @foo = opts[:foo] || 123
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  attr_reader :bar
  def initialize(opts = {})
    super(opts)
    @bar = opts[:bar] || 456
  end
end

puts Parent.new.foo # => 123
puts Parent.new(foo: 1).foo # => 1
puts Parent.new(bar: 2).foo # => 123
puts Parent.new(foo: 1, bar: 2).foo # => 1
```